# Page name shown on hover over icon is blank

Tags: matomo

When hovering over the page icon of a visit, the page name being visited normally appears. However, increasingly, that is now blank. When that happens, if I hover over the flag of the country the visit came from, it always reports "United States, Provider Charter."

Sometimes the number of page icons shown is in the hundreds and the time is hours, something that never happens other than with these blank page name icons.

Does anybody have any idea what the problem is?